# Ansible installed on Mac with success message but not found

Tags: python, ansible

I have been trying to install ansible from long time. It is giving success message when use below command.

```
Anupams-MacBook-Pro-2:bin anupamsri$ sudo pip install ansible
```

> The directory `/Users/anupamsri/Library/Caches/pip/http` or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
>
> The directory `/Users/anupamsri/Library/Caches/pip` or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
>
> Collecting ansible
>     Downloading ansible-2.4.3.0.tar.gz (6.5MB)
>       100% |████████████████████████████████| 6.5MB 200kB/s
>     Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from ansible)
>     Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from ansible)
>     Requirement already satisfied: paramiko in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from ansible)
>     Requirement already satisfied: cryptography in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from ansible)
>     Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from ansible)
>     Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from jinja2->ansible)
>     Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1>=0.1.7 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from paramiko->ansible)
>     Requirement already satisfied: bcrypt>=3.1.3 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from paramiko->ansible)
>     Requirement already satisfied: pynacl>=1.0.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from paramiko->ansible)
>     Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.4.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography->ansible)
>     Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.7; platform_python_implementation != "PyPy" in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography->ansible)
>     Requirement already satisfied: enum34; python_version < "3" in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography->ansible)
>     Requirement already satisfied: asn1crypto>=0.21.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography->ansible)
>     Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography->ansible)
>     Requirement already satisfied: ipaddress; python_version < "3" in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography->ansible)
>     Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cffi>=1.7; platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"->cryptography->ansible)
>     Installing collected packages: ansible
>     Running setup.py install for ansible ... done
>     Successfully installed ansible-2.4.3.0

=========================================

But when I check ansible version after it its not found. I also used sudo -H option but same result.

I don’t see .ansible file anywhere in system as well. Please help how to install this because I have tried brew install as well but no luck.

Anupams-MacBook-Pro-2:bin anupamsri$ ansible --version -bash: ansible: command not found

Comment: same result after installing with brew install ansible

Comment: I am currently experiencing an issue with this as well. I tried to use pip to install ansible as yum was not letting me because of package dependencies that couldnt be pulled from the current repo. if you install it through pip it goes into the python 2.7 directory however it doesn't leave you with a /etc/ansible or ansible.cfg file. I'm working on a way to rectify this myself as I am hoping to start using ansible as well.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue on OS X, based on Harold's answer I checked the `PATH` variable and was able to solve it:

I found where pip installed ansible by initiating the uninstallation process with `pip uninstall ansible`, which printed the path to the ansible files that are to be removed. Instead of confirming with *y*, I aborted the uninstallation with *n*, exported the corresponding path to the `PATH` variable and then it worked.

Update:
This approach will output various paths, the one you want to add to your `PATH` variable is the one to the `bin` folder holding the ansible commands (i.e. `ansible`, `ansible-playbook` etc.)

Comment: Path of which file did you add in your PATH variable. Uninstall command list so many files. I could not not understand which file to pickup

Comment: When you look at the paths you will see that most of them are pointing to the same binary folder which holds the basic ansible commands `ansible`, `ansible-playbook` etc. You should add the path to that `bin` folder to your `PATH` variable. I will update the answer to include this information.

Answer (score 2):

The most common cause of this, whether you're installing through `pip` or `brew`, is something not being in the `PATH`.  The second answer here should offer some insight into this, if that is indeed the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35898734/pip-installs-packages-successfully-but-executables-not-found-from-command-line/35899029

Answer (score 1):

For `zsh`, add below line in `~/.zshrc` file.

```
export PATH="/Users/shantanu/Library/Python/3.9/bin:$PATH"
```

Source it.

```
source ~/.zshrc
```